# Projective Module Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I would like a quick proof verification of the following question:

Let $R$ be a ring with identity and let $e\in R$ be idempotent. Show that the module $Re \oplus R(1-e)$ is free, thus, in particular, $Re$ is projective.

$\textit{Proof.}$ We have that $1e+1(1-e)=1\Rightarrow R=Re\oplus R(1-e)$, and since $R$ is trivially a free module over itself, $Re\oplus R(1-e)$ is free. This gives by Proposition 30 (4) in 10.5 that $Re$ is projective.

(Note Prop 30 (4) just states that if P is a direct summand of a free module implies P is projective.)

Answer (score 1):

Not really correct, in my opinion: you're given an *external* direct sum, unless you prove that the two submodules of $R$ have trivial intersection.

The intersection is indeed trivial: if $x=re\in Re\cap R(1-e)$, then $x=re(1-e)=0$. Now your argument shows that the direct sum is $R$.